# How to create a list of all values of a column in Structured Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark structured streaming job which gets records from Kafka (10,000 as maxOffsetsPerTrigger). I get all those records by spark's readStream method. This dataframe has a column named "key".

I need string(set(all values in that column 'key')) to use this string in a query to ElasticSearch.

I have already tried `df.select("key").collect().distinct()` but it throws exception:

```
 collect() is not supported with structured streaming.
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
DATAFRAME:

```
+-------+-------------------+----------+
|    key|                 ex|new column|
+-------+-------------------+----------+
| fruits|     [mango, apple]|          |
|animals|  [cat, dog, horse]|          |
|  human|[ram, shyam, karun]|          |
+-------+-------------------+----------+
```

SCHEMA:

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ex: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- new column: string (nullable = true)
```

STRING I NEED:

```
'["fruits", "animals", "human"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not apply collect on streaming dataframe. streamingDf here refers reading from Kafka.

```
val query = streamingDf
            .select(col("Key").cast(StringType))
            .writeStream
            .format("console")
            .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

It will print your data in the console. To write data in an external source, you have to give an implementation of foreachWriter. For reference, [refer](https://github.com/mahesh2492/learning-spark/tree/master/src/main/scala/streaming)

In given link, data is streamed using Kafka, read by spark and written to Cassandra eventually.

Hope, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

For such use case, I'd recommend using `foreachBatch` operator:

> **foreachBatch(function: (Dataset[T], Long) ⇒ Unit): DataStreamWriter[T]**
>
> Sets the output of the streaming query to be processed using the provided function. This is supported only the in the micro-batch execution modes (that is, when the trigger is not continuous).
>
> In every micro-batch, the provided function will be called in every micro-batch with (i) the output rows as a Dataset and (ii) the batch identifier.
>
> The batchId can be used deduplicate and transactionally write the output (that is, the provided Dataset) to external systems. The output Dataset is guaranteed to exactly same for the same batchId (assuming all operations are deterministic in the query).

Quoting the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch) (with a few modifications):

> The `foreachBatch` operation allows you to apply arbitrary operations and writing logic on the output of a streaming query.
>
> `foreachBatch` allows arbitrary operations and custom logic on the output of each micro-batch.

And in the same [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch) you can find a sample code that shows that you could do your use case fairly easily.

```
streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  batchDF.select("key").collect().distinct()
}
```